# Using database with Hadoop cluster

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, acid

Currently I have a small Hadoop cluster that performs a MapReduce task on my input data and generates some output. What I would like to do is store this data in a database so that it can be queried for analysis. I would like the database to simulate the ACID  properties, so that any change in one node is reflected upon the entire cluster. Then if a node fails there will be others containing the current data.

I have been researching things like Hive with its ACID transactions, but is this all I would need to accomplish that?

Comment: Hive requires a metastore such as Mysql or Postgres to accomplish this. Which if you have these anyway, why not just use a clustered deployment of those?

Comment: Thanks that's what I was thinking. I am still new to this area so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I personally don't have much experience with Hive ACID transactions, but I find many people using Cassandra, Hbase, or Couchbase instead of Hive for simple updates like you're asking

Comment: Hive provides ACID transactions only for ORC format . You might consider looking into other databases as mentioned by @cricket 007

Comment: btw, Hive isn't actually a database. It's only SQL engine on Hadoop

Comment: Yes I have looked into Hbase more and I think it will work for me.